# Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop. Unable to find code which is causing it

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

this functional component is re-rendering-

```
   const Profile = () => {
          const dispatch = useDispatch()
          const getProfile = useSelector((state) => state.getProfile);
          const logging = useSelector((state) => state.logging);
          const { profile} = getProfile;
          const { userInfo } = logging;
          const [profileDetails, setprofileDetails] = useState({ 
            bio: " ",
            social: {
              facebook: " ",
              youtube: " ",
              instagram: " ",
              linkedin: " ",
              twitter: " ",
              github: " ",
            },
          });
         
          setprofileDetails(profile);
         
        
          useEffect(() => {
            dispatch(getProfileAction())
           
          }, [ dispatch]);
```

I dont know how its happening , please help. i have tried putting setState inside useEffecft and also using only '[]' as useEffect dependency (even though console was prompting me to add other dependencies) yet its re-rendering infinitely .

REST OF CODE-

```
 return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.profileEdit}>
        <div div className='container'>
          <div className={classes.profileEditgrid}>
            <div className={classes.profileEditimg}>
              <img src='/images/potrait.jpg' alt='profile' />
            </div>
            <div className={classes.profileEditProfile}>
              <div className={classes.ProfileLink}>
                <p>
                  <i className='fas fa-link'> </i>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className={classes.ProfileLink}>
                <p>
                  <i className='fas fa-link'> </i>
                </p>
              </div>
              <h1>{userInfo.name}</h1>
              <h2>
                <i className='fas fa-envelope-square'></i>
                {userInfo.email}
              </h2>
              <div className={classes.profileEditformdiv1}>
                <h4>basic info</h4>
                <form className={classes.ProfileEditForm1}>
                  <label htmlFor='bio'>Bio</label>
                  <p name='bio'>{profileDetails.bio}</p>

                  <label htmlFor='dob'>Date of birth</label>
                  <p name='dob'></p>
                  <label htmlFor='location'>Location</label>
                  <p name='location'>{profileDetails.location}</p>
                  <label htmlFor='status'>Status</label>
                  <select name='status'>
                    <option>single</option>
                    <option>married</option>
                    <option>complicated</option>
                  </select>
                </form>
              </div>
              <p className={classes.ProfileEditgap}> </p>
              <div className={classes.profileEditformdiv2}>
                <h4>education</h4>
                <form className={classes.ProfileEditForm2}>
                  <label htmlFor='school'>school</label>
                  <input type='text' name='school' placeholder='school' />
                  <label htmlFor='degree'>degree</label>
                  <input type='text' name='degree' placeholder='degree' />
                  <label htmlFor='field of study'>field of study</label>
                  <input
                    type='text'
                    name='field of study'
                    placeholder='field of study'
                  />
                  <label htmlFor='from'>from</label>
                  <input type='text' name='from' placeholder='from' />
                  <label htmlFor='to'>to</label>
                  <input type='text' name='to' placeholder='to' />
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.ProfileEditSocial}>
            <h4>social links</h4>
            <form className={classes.ProfileEditform3}>
              <div>
                <p>
                  <a href={profileDetails.social.facebook}>
                    <i className='fab fa-facebook' />
                  </a>
                </p>

                <p>
                  <a href={profileDetails.social.twitter}>
                    <i className='fab fa-twitter'></i>
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p>
                  <a href={profileDetails.social.youtube}>
                    <i className='fab fa-youtube'></i>
                  </a>
                </p>

                <p>
                  <a href={profileDetails.social.instagram}>
                    <i className='fab fa-instagram'></i>
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p>
                  <a href={profileDetails.social.github}>
                    <i className='fab fa-github'></i>
                  </a>
                </p>
                <p>
                  <a href={profileDetails.social.linkedin}>
                    <i className='fab fa-linkedin'></i>
                  </a>
                </p>
              </div>
            </form>
            <Link to='/profile/edit'>
              <button>Edit</button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Profile;
```

so the button click function is only taking me to other page and not doing anything on this page

Comment: You are updating state with `setprofileDetails` directly in your component, which causes a re-render, and the infinite loop continue. If you want the default value of `profileDetails` to be `profile` you can write `const [profileDetails, setprofileDetails] = useState(profile);`.

Comment: that will cause it to be null as profile is null in the beginning and fetches value after useEffect

Comment: how does the getProfileAction code looks like?

Comment: `setprofileDetails` is causing this. Either wrap it up inside a useEffect, or set the default state to `profile` object

Comment: setting it to `profile` as default state also didnt help as i could see it calling actions infinitely in redux devtools. Having two useEffects solved it . but was wondering was there any other way apart from using button "Onclick" to call once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `setprofileDetails` in the body of the component, which is essentially the render method, so its trying to infinitely rerender (render, setprofileDetails, render, setprofileDetails ...)

You need to call `setprofileDetails` from either an effect or the likes of a click handler

e.g. an effect -

```
useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(getProfileAction())
}, [dispatch])

useEffect(() => {
   setprofileDetails(profile)
}, [profile])
```

Note the profile as the dependency in the array, therefore anytime `profile` changes, it will rerun the affect and set the state.

Comment: i have tried that . i have done this - `useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProfileAction())
    setprofileDetails(profile);
   
  }, [ dispatch, profile,]);` yet its still re-rendering as i can see in redux-devtools

Comment: I would expect it to rerender, just not infinitely with the initial error message

Comment: i have to dispatch action in order to get profile for first time , otherwise it will be null. and in redux-devtools its showing continuously - `GETPROFILE_REQ GETPROFILE_SUCCESS GETPROFILE_REQ GETPROFILE_SUCCESS.......`

Comment: see my edit, just have them as two separate hooks

Comment: it did it . thanks a lot . i didnt know we can use multiple seperate useEffect in a component . i dont know why you were downvoted . WOuld have upvoted if i was allowed.Thanks

Comment: good stuff, regarding multiple hooks, absolutely, hooks are different from the old class lifecycle methods, they should encapsulate code that should run due to their similar dependencies being updated, rather than thinking in the old lifecycle methods (on mount, on update etc)